# How to display the text of a hyperlink in SharePoint

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I am trying to display the text of a hyperlink. The hyperlink is obtained from a query, and its column type is `Publishing Hyperlink`.

This code `<xsl:value-of select="$Link" />` display the full link

```
<a href="...">File 1</a>
```

How can I just display the text of the link?

```
File
```

Is there some code like `<xsl:text-of select="$Link" />` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="YOUR ANCHOR TEXT TAG IN XML HERE"/>
```

Replace your link text tag name you have given in your xml file with "YOUR ANCHOR TEXT TAG IN XML HERE"

This will display the anchor text for sure.

See the example below

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
<link>http://www.google.com</link>
<text>google</text>
</cd>
<cd>
<link>http://www.yahoo.com</link>
<text>yahoo</text>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th style="text-align:left">Anchor Link</th>
  <th style="text-align:left">Anchor Text</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="link"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="text"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

Please click on the url to see output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp24I.jpg

Comment: Sorry but my source is from a SharePoint list. Not from an xml. The field is a "Publishing Hyperlink" type.

Answer (score 0):

According DataSource details:

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNc9K.png)

Using:

```
<xsl:text-of select="$Link.desc" />
```

Should work.